# How can I configure iPXE menu settings to boot Plop Boot Manager?

Tags: linux, networking, boot, pxe

I have created a big iPXE server based on an Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 system. I have entries for different Linux images, Windows installers and Clonezilla Live.
Now I want to include also an entry for **Plop Boot Manager**, and I'm finding that there is not any documentation available to do it, even in the plop boot manager official site.

I have a boot menu called boot.ipxe, configured based on [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/).

I have tried to add a simple entry to boot plop boot manager, but when I try to start it, it fails. This is the content of the entry:

```
:plpbt-5.0.15
kernel http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.bin
initrd http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.img vga=1 nfsmount=192.168.1.2:/free/pxe/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/ nomodeset
boot
```

The resulting error, when I try to boot that entry, is as follows:

```
http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.bin... ok
http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.img... ok
Could not boot: Error 0x2a818006 (https://ipxe.org/2a818006)
Could not boot: Error 0x2a818006 (https://ipxe.org/2a818006)
Insert system disk in drive.
Press any key when ready....
```

The root of the http server (apache2) is well configured (I use it already for other entries), but just in case you need it: it's `/free/pxe`
The NFS server is configured to share `/free/pxe` (read-only)
I have tried to search for some documentation on what kinds of files does the iPXE menu need to recieve as kernel and initrd, but I think there are not a lot of information on this matter.

So does anybody know how should I configure the iPXE entry for Plop Boot Manager?

Let me show you the tree command for the `plpbt-5.0.15` directory:

```
.
├── 1README.TXT
├── doc
│   ├── liesmich.html
│   ├── liesmich.txt
│   ├── readme.html
│   └── readme.txt
├── experimental
│   └── usb4ksector
│       ├── 1README.TXT
│       ├── plpbt.bin
│       ├── plpbtrom.bin
│       ├── plpinstc.com
│       └── plpinst.com
├── install
│   ├── plpbtin.img
│   ├── plpbtin.iso
│   ├── plpinstc.com
│   └── plpinst.com
├── licence.txt
├── Linux
│   ├── 1README.TXT
│   ├── plpbt.bin
│   ├── plpbtrom
│   ├── plpbtrom.bin
│   ├── plpcfgbt
│   └── plpmkboot
├── pcmcia
│   ├── install
│   │   ├── plpbtin.img
│   │   ├── plpbtin.iso
│   │   ├── plpinstc.com
│   │   └── plpinst.com
│   ├── plpbt.bin
│   ├── plpbt.img
│   ├── plpbt.iso
│   └── plpbtrom.bin
├── plpbt.bin
├── plpbt.img
├── plpbt.iso
├── plpbtrom.bin
└── Windows
    ├── 1README.html
    ├── InstallToBootMenu.bat
    ├── InstallToMBR.bat
    ├── plpbt4win.exe
    ├── plpbt.bin
    ├── plpbtrom.bin
    ├── plpbtrom.exe
    ├── plpcfgbt.exe
    ├── plpcfgbtGUI.exe
    ├── plpinstc.bin
    └── plpmkboot.exe
```

--EDIT--

I realized that, from my experience, the arguments in the entries of the ipxe config file, generally are better put after the `kernel` line - I had seen that before - so I tried putting in `kernel` instead of `initrd`, as follows:

```
:plpbt-5.0.15
kernel http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.bin vga=1 nfsmount=192.168.1.2:/free/pxe/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/ nomodeset
initrd http://192.168.1.2/os-images/plpbt-5.0.15/plpbt.img
boot
```

Anyway, it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you look up the error message `Could not boot: Error 0x2a818006` and what of the suggestions that come up have you tried?

Comment: I had looked at the link that appears in the error - https://ipxe.org/2a818006 but not in google. I've seen now and there's only a thread in the iPXE forum, but that case is not showing the error, only google found that because they wrote somewhere a message in case that error appears. Other than that, there's not any more matches in google.
In the link I mentioned before I didn't found anything that I understand/see useful

Comment: I edited the question - please see also

Answer (score 1):

I have made an approach to integrate plop boot manager into my iPXE menu.

The key on what I did, is chainloading into the PXE netboot-sample example available in the plop boot manager [Website](https://www.plop.at/en/ploplinux/live/networkboot-linux.html) - [link for the file](https://download.plop.at/ploplinux/22.2/netboot/netboot-sample.tar.gz). That is a preconfigured PXE working sample, so that the user doesn't need to configure anything, except only DHCP - TFTP - and maybe something more, etc.

The menu entry for chainloading into plop menu is as follows:

```
:chainplop
set 210:string tftp://192.168.1.2/ploplinux-netboot/
set 209:string pxelinux.cfg/default
chain http://192.168.1.2/ploplinux-netboot/pxelinux.0
```

the set commands, I found out thanks to someone in the ipxe forum - [iPXE forum](https://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=7267)
So, when I enter in `:chainplop` option, it loads PXE (not iPXE) and I can choose Plop Boot Manager, which is what I initially wanted.

Comment: This approach is sufficient, but I'd like to do a more direct approach, directly integrating plop boot manager in my iPXE menu. That's why I will not accept my own answer as valid answer, but hopefully an answer from someone who could tell me how to do the way I want to do.